# Android partial string keyword match

Tags: java, android, string, match, keyword

In android, I have a main string and another string which has keyword(s) separated by space(s).
I want to output a string where the main string having matching keywords is highlighted.

Ex.

```
String strMain = "This string contains     the main contents.";

String strSearchKeywords = "this cont";
```

The resulting output must be something like:

```
String strResult = "<b>This</b> string <b>cont</b>ains     the main <b>cont</b>ents.";
```

One way is to split the search keywords into an array-list and then iterate through each of the items and highlight the main content.

However, is there any other way in one go without iterating, like using regex match?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strMain = strMain .replaceAll("(?i)(" + strSearchKeywords.replace(' ', '|') + ")",
        "<b>$1</b>");
```

Which means

```
strMain = strMain .replaceAll("(?i)(this|cont)",
        "<b>$1</b>");
```

The `(?i)` sets the ignore-case flag.